# C++ and STL - Machine Learning Problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, object-oriented, stl, machine-learning

I would like to get some general comments on style and use of STL in particular. This is some code I wrote to do machine learning classification (logistic regression). Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

A record containing an individual training example:

```
/*
 * A class representing a single record to be used for training or evaluation
 * of a classifier. This record contains a vector of predictors which are
 * observations used to predict an outcome, together with a target outcome for
 * that observation. The machine learning algorithm's job is to learn to
 * generalize this predictor to target outcome relationship.
 */
#include "Record.h"
using namespace std;

/**
 * Construct a record from the provided predictor Vector and target outcome.
 */
Record::Record(const Vector& predictor, double target) :
    predictor_(predictor), target_(target) {
}

/**
 * Construct a record by parsing the provided string. The string must contain
 * a set of space seperated values, with the target outcome in column kTargetCol
 * and the predictor vector starting on column kPredictorCol. Note that each
 * element of the predictor vector is preceeded by an index and a colon. So
 * the string looks has the following form:
 * <label> <target_outcome> 1:<predictor_element1> 2:<predictor_element2> ...
 */
Record::Record(const string& line) {
  Init(line);
}

void Record::Init(const string& line) {
  stringstream line_stream(line);
  string token;
  for (int i = 0; getline(line_stream, token, ' '); ++i) {
    if (i == kTargetCol) {
      istringstream istream(token);
      double target;
      istream >> target;
      target_ = target;
    }
    if (i >= kPredictorCol) {
      istringstream istream(token.substr(token.find(':') + 1));
      double element;
      istream >> element;
      predictor_.push_back(element);
    }
  }
}

/** Convert a record into a string suitable for display */
string Record::String() const {
  ostringstream sstream;
  sstream << target_;
  return sstream.str() + ", " + predictor_.String();
}
```

A collection of training examples:

```
/*
 * A class representing a collection of records to be used for training or
 * evaluation of a classifier.
 */
#include "RecordList.h"
using namespace std;
/**
 * Initialize a list of training/test records from the provided filename.
 */
RecordList::RecordList(const string& filename) {
  input_file_.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
  Init();
}

void RecordList::Init() {
  for (string line; getline(input_file_, line);) {
    Record record(line);
    records_.push_back(record);
  }
}

RecordList::~RecordList() {
  input_file_.close();
}


/**
 * A constant version of an iterator pointing to the beginning of the record
 * list. Used for doing read only iterations through the list.
 */
vector<Record>::const_iterator RecordList::const_begin() const {
  return records_.begin();
}

/**
 * A constant version of an iterator pointing to the end of the record list.
 * Used for doing read only iterations through the list.
 */
vector<Record>::const_iterator RecordList::const_end() const {
  return records_.end();
}

/**
 * A regular version of an iterator pointing to the beginning of the record list.
 * Used for doing iterations through the list that modify records.
 */
vector<Record>::iterator RecordList::begin() {
  return records_.begin();
}

/**
 * A regular version of an iterator pointing to the end of the record list.
 * Used for doing iterations through the list that modify records.
 */
vector<Record>::iterator RecordList::end() {
  return records_.end();
}

/**
 * Get the number of elements in the predictor vectors. Note that this is the
 * same for all records;
 */
int RecordList::RecordSize() const {
  return records_[0].predictor().size();
}

/** Get the average of the predictors. */
Vector RecordList::Mean() const {
  Vector mean(RecordSize());
  for (vector<Record>::const_iterator itr = const_begin(); itr != const_end();
      ++itr) {
    mean = mean + itr->predictor();
  }
  return mean / records_.size();
}

/** Get the variance of the predictors. */
Vector RecordList::SqrtVar() const {
  Vector var(RecordSize());
  Vector mean = Mean();
  for (vector<Record>::const_iterator itr = const_begin(); itr != const_end();
      ++itr) {
    var = var + (itr->predictor() - mean).Square();
  }
  return (var / records_.size()).Sqrt();
}

/** Convert the record list into a string suitable for display. */
string RecordList::String() const {
  string result = "";
  int i = 0;
  for (vector<Record>::const_iterator itr = records_.begin();
      itr != records_.end(); ++itr) {
    if (i++ == 10) {
      return result + "...\n";
    }
    result += itr->String() + "\n";
  }
  return result;
}
```

A normalizer used to pre-process each training sample:

```
/**
 * A class for normalizing records.
 */
#include "Normalizer.h"

/**
 * Construct a normalizer suitable for the provided RecordList by calculating
 * the mean and square root of the underlying predictor Vectors.
 */
Normalizer::Normalizer(const RecordList& recordList)
    : mean_(recordList.Mean()), sqrt_var_(recordList.SqrtVar()) {}

/**
 * Normalize a RecordList by subtracting the mean from each predictor Vector
 * and dividing by the square root of the variance.
 */
void Normalizer::Normalize(RecordList& recordList) const {
  for (vector<Record>::iterator itr = recordList.begin();
      itr != recordList.end(); ++itr) {
    itr->set_predictor(Normalize(itr->predictor()));
  }
}

/**
 * Normalize an individual predictor Vector.
 */
Vector Normalizer::Normalize(const Vector& v) const {
  return (v - mean_) / sqrt_var_;
}
```

The classifier itself:

```
/**
 * A class representing a logistic regression classifier. This classifier can
 * predict the target outcome for any given predictor Vector. It can also be
 * trained by the Trainer class given a suitable training RecordList.
 */
#include "Classifier.h"
using namespace std;

/**
 * Construct a classifier for the provided training set and normalizer. This
 * initializes the weight Vector to have all zero. A Trainer must be applied
 * to the Classifier before it can be used.
 */
Classifier::Classifier(const RecordList& training_set,
    const Normalizer& normalizer) :
    normalizer_(normalizer),
    weights_(Vector(training_set.RecordSize())) {}

/**
 * Classify the provided predictor Vector. This provides an estimate of the
 * target outcome.
 */
double Classifier::Classify(const Vector& v) const {
  Vector vn = normalizer_.Normalize(v);
  return 2.0 * Sigmoid(weights_.InnerProduct(vn)) - 1.0;
}

/**
 * Calculate the sigmoid (logistic function) of the given value.
 */
double Classifier::Sigmoid(double x) const {
  return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
}

/**
 * Evaluate performance of the classifier using the provided test RecordList.
 */
int Classifier::EvaluatePerformance(const RecordList& test_set) const {
  int total = 0;
  int correct = 0;
  for (vector<Record>::const_iterator itr = test_set.const_begin();
      itr != test_set.const_end(); ++itr) {
    double result = Classify(itr->predictor());
    total++;
    if ((result < 0 && itr->target() < 0)
        || (result > 0 && itr->target() > 0)) {
      correct++;
    }
  }
  return (100*correct) / total;
}
```

A class for training the classifier:

```
/**
 * A class for training a classifier.
 */
#include "Trainer.h"
using namespace std;
static const double kTrainingRate = 0.01;
static const string kTrainingFile = "data/training.txt";
static const string kTestFile = "data/test.txt";

/**
 * Construct a Trainer using the provided training rate. Higher training rates
 * will lead to faster convergence but higher asymptotic error.
 */
Trainer::Trainer(double training_rate) : training_rate_(training_rate) {}

/**
 * Train a classifier using stochastic gradient descent. At each iteration
 * the classifier weights are updated based on the delta between the estimate
 * from the classifier and the target outcome.
 */
void Trainer::Train(const RecordList& training_records,
    Classifier& classifier) {
  Vector delta;
  for (vector<Record>::const_iterator itr = training_records.const_begin();
      itr != training_records.const_end(); ++itr) {
    double estimate = classifier.Classify(itr->predictor());
    double estimation_error = estimate - itr->target();
    delta = itr->predictor() * (training_rate_ * estimation_error);
    classifier.set_weights(classifier.weights() - delta);
  }
}

/**
 * The main program. Loads a set of training records and normalizes them. It
 * then uses these records to train a classifier before evaluating the
 * classifier's performance on a second set of test records.
 */
int main() {
  RecordList training_records(kTrainingFile);
  Normalizer normalizer(training_records);
  Classifier classifier(training_records, normalizer);
  Trainer trainer(kTrainingRate);
  trainer.Train(training_records, classifier);
  RecordList test_records(kTestFile);
  printf("Percentage of correct classifications: %d%%\n",
      classifier.EvaluatePerformance(test_records));
}
```

And finally a class for representing mathematical vectors (essentially just arrays of doubles):

```
/**
 * A class to represent a vector which is an array of doubles. Supports various
 * calculations like addition, subtraction and inner product.
 */
#include "Vector.h"
using namespace std;

Vector::Vector() : elements(vector<double>()) {}

Vector::Vector(int size) : elements(vector<double>(size, 0)) {}

Vector::Vector(const vector<double>& values) : elements(values) {}

int Vector::size() const {
  return elements.size();
}

double Vector::operator[](int index) const {
  return elements[index];
}

/**
 * A constant version of an iterator pointing ot the beginning of the vector.
 * Used for doing a read only iteration through the vector.
 */
vector<double>::const_iterator Vector::const_begin() const {
  return elements.begin();
}

/**
* A constant version of an iterator pointing ot the end of the vector.
* Used for doing a read only iteration through the vector.
*/
vector<double>::const_iterator Vector::const_end() const {
  return elements.end();
}

/**
 * A regular version of an iterator pointing to the beginning of the vector.
 * Used for doing iterations through the vector that modify elements.
 */
vector<double>::iterator Vector::begin() {
  return elements.begin();
}

/**
 * A regular version of an iterator pointing to the end of the vector.
 * Used for doing iterations through the vector that modify elements.
 */
vector<double>::iterator Vector::end() {
  return elements.end();
}

/** Convert a Vector into a string suitable for display. */
string Vector::String() const {
  string result = "[ ";
  for (vector<double>::const_iterator itr = elements.begin();
      itr != elements.end(); ++itr) {
    ostringstream sstream;
    sstream << *itr;
    result += sstream.str() + " ";
  }
  result += ("]");
  if (result.size() > 50) {
    return result.substr(0, 47) + " ... ]";
  }
  return result;
}

void Vector::push_back(double value) {
  elements.push_back(value);
}

/**
 * Calculate the inner product of two Vectors by taking the sum of the products
 * of the corresponding elements.
 */
double Vector::InnerProduct(const Vector& operand) const {
  return inner_product(const_begin(), const_end(), operand.const_begin(), 0);
}

Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& operand) const {
  Vector result(size());
  transform(const_begin(), const_end(), operand.const_begin(), result.begin(),
      plus<double>());
  return result;
}

Vector Vector::operator-(const Vector& operand) const {
  Vector result(size());
  transform(const_begin(), const_end(), operand.const_begin(), result.begin(),
      minus<double>());
  return result;
}

/** Functor for multiplying a Vector by a scalar. */
struct MultiplyScalar {
public:
  MultiplyScalar(double scalar) : scalar(scalar) {}
  double operator()(double x) {
    return x * scalar;
  }
private:
  double scalar;
};

Vector Vector::operator*(double multiplier) const {
  Vector result(size());
  transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), result.elements.begin(),
      MultiplyScalar(multiplier));
  return result;
}

Vector Vector::operator/(const Vector& divisor) const {
  Vector result(size());
  transform(const_begin(), const_end(), divisor.const_begin(), result.begin(),
      divides<double>());
  return result;
}

/** Functor for dividing a Vector by a scalar. */
struct DivideScalar {
public:
  DivideScalar(double scalar) : scalar(scalar) {}
  double operator()(double x) {
    return x / scalar;
  }
private:
  double scalar;
};

Vector Vector::operator/(double divisor) const {
  Vector result(size());
  transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), result.elements.begin(),
      DivideScalar(divisor));
  return result;
}

double OpSquare(double x) {
  return x*x;
}

/** Calculate the element-wise square of a Vector. */
Vector Vector::Square() const {
  Vector result(size());
  transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), result.elements.begin(),
      OpSquare);
  return result;
}

/** Calculate the element-wise square root of a Vector. */
Vector Vector::Sqrt() const {
  Vector result(size());
  transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), result.elements.begin(),
      sqrt);
  return result;
}

double OpSigmoid(double z) {
  return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-z));
}

/** Calculate the element-wise sigmoid of a Vector. */
Vector Vector::Sigmoid() const{
  Vector result(size());
  transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), result.elements.begin(),
      OpSigmoid);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit (based on the large number of additions) I am re-writing this:

#### General Notes:

You should add header guards to all your *.h files.

#### Vector.h

Don't like your use of string conversion methods. Very Java like and not C++ like at all. Prefer to write stream operators which are much more versatile.

```
  string String() const;

  // Prefer

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream stream, Vector const& data)
  {
      return stream;
  }
```

Hide your implementation details by using local typedefs. Also it is more traditional to just call the method to get a const iterator `begin()` rather than `const_begin()` etc.

```
  vector<double>::const_iterator const_begin() const;
  vector<double>::iterator begin();

  // Prefer
  typedef std::vector<double>       Container;
  typedef Container::iterator       iterator;
  typedef Container::const_iterator const_iterator;

  iterator       begin();
  const_iterator begin() const;
```

This works but it also allows some expressions that don't do much;

```
  double operator[](int index) const;

  // Now the compiler will allow:

  Vector  x;
  x[5] = 6;   // Will compile but not do anything.
              // I would prefer this fails to compile so that the
              // user of the class will know that they have done
              // something wrong immediately.

  // Thus I would prefer this declaration:
  double const& operator[](std::size_t index) const;
```

Not totally convinced that setting up these operators will make using the class easier to read.

```
  Vector operator+(const Vector& operand) const;
  Vector operator-(double scalar) const;
  Vector operator-(const Vector& operand) const;
  Vector operator*(double scalar) const;
  Vector operator/(double scalar) const;
  Vector operator/(const Vector& operand) const;
```

Surprised this compiles at all here:

```
private:
  vector<double> elements;
```

The header file should include all the header files it need to make the required types available. There is no `#include <vector>` in this file. Also you do not prefix `vector` with `std::` so how does it know where it is defined.

There are a couple of explanations to both these problems none of them good.

**NEVER** put `using namespace std;` in a header file.
**NEVER** make a header file depend on being included in the correct order.

#### Vector.cpp

```
Vector::Vector() : elements(vector<double>()) {}
// Easier to write:
Vector::Vector() : elements() {}


Vector::Vector(int size) : elements(vector<double>(size, 0)) {}    
// Easier to write
Vector::Vector(int size) : elements(size) {} // Value defaults to 0
```

I would use the correct type. here.

```
int Vector::size() const {return elements.size();}
// I would use:
std::size_t Vector::size() const {return elements.size();}
```

As described above I would return by const reference.

```
double Vector::operator[](int index) const {
  return elements[index];
}
```

Here I would not convert to a string.
I would a stream operator (then use some algorithms inside to make it cleaner).

```
/** Convert a Vector into a string suitable for display. */
string Vector::String() const {

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Vector const& data)
{
   stream << "[ ";
   std::copy(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(stream," "));
   
   stream << "] ";
   return stream;
}
```

I will add more when I get some time.

### Old review.

Rather than write a to_string() method:

```
string Record::String() const {
  ostringstream sstream;
  sstream << target_;
  return sstream.str() + ", " + predictor_.String();
}
```

Write a stream operator.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::stream& stream, Record const& data)
{
     return stream << data.target_ << ", " << data.predictor_;
}
```

If you really just want a string use lexical cast:

```
Record  record(/* Initialization*/);

// lexical_cast use the stream operator.
std::string data = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(record);
```

I don't see the need for a file-stream member that is kept open for the life of the object. Open it use it then let it fall out of scope:

```
RecordList::RecordList(const string& filename) {
  input_file_.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
  Init();
}

void RecordList::Init() {
  for (string line; getline(input_file_, line);) {
    Record record(line);
    records_.push_back(record);
  }
}

RecordList::~RecordList() {
  input_file_.close();
}

I would just do:

RecordList::RecordList(const string& filename) {
  Init(filename);
}

void RecordList::Init(std::string const& filename) {
  std::ifstream  input_file(filename.c_str());
  for (string line; getline(input_file, line);) {
    Record record(line);
    records_.push_back(record);
  }
}

RecordList::~RecordList() {}
```

Here you are exposing an implementation detail:

```
 vector<Record>::const_iterator RecordList::const_begin() const {
```

The user of your class should not need to know that you are using a vector internal to your class

```
class RecordList
{
    public:
      typedef  std::vector<Record>        Container;
      typedef  Container::iterator        iterator;
      typedef  Container::const_iterator  const_iterator;

      const_iterator   RecordList::const_begin() const;
};
```

Where you can try and use standard algorithms rather than loops:

```
Vector mean(RecordSize());
for (vector<Record>::const_iterator itr = const_begin(); itr != const_end();
    ++itr) {
  mean = mean + itr->predictor();
}
```

I would try and do t for you but I can tell what the type `Vector` really is. It looks like it should be some container type but you use it like a scaler type on the next line.

```
return mean / records_.size();
```

Comment: Fantastic. The Vector class is at the bottom. I've used operator overloading so you can divide the vector by a scalar (in this case the same scalar is used for every element of the vector). Could you please give it quick sanity check? Thank you again.

Comment: @padawan: Same comment as RecordList: "You are exposing implementation details".

Comment: @padawan: PS. it would be better to include both header and source files. Put the names of the files above each code block.

Comment: @padawan: PPS. This is a lot of code for one question. In the future it may be worth spreading it across multiple questions on multiple days. Then you can incorporate feedback in new questions.

Comment: Thanks Loki. So I should use typedef as above to hide the implementation details?

Comment: One other question, the input file is actually formatted like this:

somelabel +1 1:0.542 2:0.389 3:0.584 ...
othrlabel -1 1:0.232 2:0.231 3:0.233 ...

I need to extract the double that follows the colon in each word, not before the colon. Is there a simple way I can do this similar to what you suggested?

Comment: @padawan: Misread that bit of code. I have removed the comment above (but I still think it can be simplified slightly).

Comment: If you can help me use a standard algorithm for the accumulation (and do a quick sanity check of my use of transform in Vector) the bounty is yours. Thanks again!

Comment: @padawan: `sum = std::accumulate(begin, end, 0);` See: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html. The transform looks good. Personally I would have used the standard multipler (but that is just taste yours is fine). `transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), result.elements.begin(), std::bind1st(std::multiplies<double>(), multiplier));`

Comment: Thanks Loki. Could you give some general advice on the use of namespaces. Should I be using anonymous namespaces here instead of using namespace std?

Comment: @padawan: The way you phrase the question indicates you don't quite understand the concept. This might be a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com . But in general 1) don't use `using namespace XXX;` Put you code in your own namespace (I own the domain plopplop.com (not real) as a result I put all my code into the namespace `plopplop` and create sub namespaces in there). This avoid contention with other code I integrate with. The anonymous namespace is the equivalent to using global static variables (just a preferred technique).

Comment: I meant should I used an anonymous namespace to keep the functors only visible within the files where they are defined?

Comment: @padawan: I would start a discussion on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ about that topic. It is a bit bigger than I can answer in comments and I am sure you can get more feedback from the people there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered passing output arguments using pointers instead of by reference?

That way it's clearer in your method call what the input and output arguments are, e.g instead of

```
trainer.Train(training_records, classifier);
```

you would have

```
trainer.Train(training_records, &classifier);
```

Comment: Don't agree with that at all.

Comment: Please elaborate.